# Associate Arguments Call in PHP

Tags: php

Can I load the php functions to call with associative arguments? Something like this:

```
function foo($id,$name,$address){
}
```

and call like this:

```
function foo(
    $address : "45, Baker St. London",
    $id      : "34",
    $name    : "Albert"

);
```

Comment: As always, RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP uses default values to achieve what you most likely are looking for:

```
function foo ($address="123 Fake Street",$name="John Doe",$id=12345)
{
    return $address.', '.$name.', '.$id;
}
```

then you can do

```
foo("1 east 1st");// "1 east 1st, John Doe, 12345
```

To more directly answer your question, one way would be with an associative array.

```
function foo2 ($args) {
    extract($args);
    return $address.', '.$name.', '.$id;
}

$args=array(
    'address'=>'123 Fake Street',
    'name'=>'John Doe',
    'id'=>12345
)

foo2($args);// "123 Fake Street, John Doe, 12345"
```

A more robust version, which will assign defaults for missing values, might look like this:

```
function foo3 ($args) {
    extract($args);
    $address=isset($address) ? $address : "123 Fake Street";
    $name=isset($name) ? $name : "John Doe";
    $id=isset($id) ? $id : 12345;
    return $address.', '.$name.', '.$id;
}

foo3(array('name'=>'Jim Dandy')); //"123 Fake Street, Jim Dandy, 12345"
```

Answer (score 1):

No, named parameters are currently not possible. [They are "planned" for whatever future version.](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params)

You may use an associative array.

Comment: *You may use an associative array.* Can you please give a example for OP?

Comment: @GhostGambler Comment on the performance of associative array as an argument?

Comment: @user3581203 Since PHP is basically not directed at optimizing performance, but in optimizing the speed of code writing, I would say one can neglect the performance dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [default argument values](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default).

```
function foo($id = "34", $name = "Albert", $address = "45, Baker St. London"){
}
```

Comment: If I already know them on writing function, why do I need to make them arguments?